# массовое использование регулярных выражений для замены текста в строке (javascript)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки, replace

Приветствую!

У меня в javascript проекте очень много операций формирования текста, например

```
var htmlCode = 'text ' + var1 + ' text ' + var2 + ' text ' + (exp ? var31 : var32) + ' text';

$(element).append(htmlCode);
```

, но при этом формируется такой текст относительно редко (не чаще 100 раз в секунду, а часто и просто однократно)

В настоящий момент такие 'портянки' стало очень тяжело воспринимать и править, поэтому хочу заменить их следующим кодом

```
var htmlCode = f('text {var1} text {var2} text {var3} text', {
    var1: value1,
    var2: value2,
    var3: (exp ? var31 : var32),
});

$(element).append(htmlCode);
```

где функция f с помощью регулярных выражений производит автоматическую замену {} вставок, например:

```
function f(s, c){
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; });
    };
```

Подскажите, насколько оправдан такой подход? Не скажется ли такое массовое использование регулярных выражений на производительность и другие характеристики?

Comment: Проверяйте. Думаю, что при разовом формировании это вполне актуально. При `100 раз в секунду` нужно смотреть

Comment: А чем не угодили шаблонные строки: `let htmlCode = \`text ${var1} text ${var2} text ${exp ? var31 : var32} text\`;`? Ну, кроме того, что их не поддерживает IE, но на это есть babel.

Comment: Yaant 1 , а как это в js сделать без всяких дополнительных средств?

Comment: В актуальных версиях браузеров (кроме IE и Opera Mini) это вот именно так и работает в js, никакие дополнительные средства не нужны.

Comment: Yaant, в том то и дело, что "кроме IE" :'(